# Configure Atlantis

Tags: amazon-web-services, atlantis

I've trouble with setting up the Atlantis Pull Request on EKS ( used Helm Chart ). When I tried to push a code commit, it display an error "This repo is not allowlisted for Atlantis."

Here is my values.yaml

```
## -------------------------- ##
# Values to override for your instance.
## -------------------------- ##

# Provide a name to substitute for the full names of resources
fullnameOverride: ""

# Provide a name to substitute for the name of the chart
nameOverride: ""

## An option to override the atlantis url,
##   if not using an ingress, set it to the external IP.
# atlantisUrl: http://10.0.0.0

# Replace this with your own repo allowlist:
orgAllowlist: "dev.azure.com/PHARMACITYJSC/Pharmacity%20Digital/atlantis"
logLevel: "debug"

# Deprecated in favor of orgAllowlist
# orgWhitelist:  dev.azure.com/PHARMACITYJSC/Pharmacity%20Digital/atlantis

# If using Azure DevOps, specify like the following:
azuredevops:
  user: $$$$$$$$$$$$
  token: $$$$$$$$$$$$$
  webhookUser: $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
  webhookPassword: $$$$$$$$$$$$

# To specify AWS credentials to be mapped to ~/.aws or to aws.directory:
aws: 
  credentials: |
    [default]
    aws_access_key_id=EXAMPLE
    aws_secret_access_key=EXAMPLE
    region=ap-southeast-1
  config: |
    [profile a_role_to_assume]
    role_arn = arn:aws:iam::191227657176:user/test
    source_profile = default
  directory: "/home/atlantis/.aws"


## -------------------------- ##
# Default values for atlantis (override as needed).
## -------------------------- ##

image:
  repository: ghcr.io/runatlantis/atlantis
  # if not set appVersion field from Chart.yaml is used
  tag: ""
  pullPolicy: Always


## Use Server Side Repo Config,
## ref: https://www.runatlantis.io/docs/server-side-repo-config.html
## Example default configuration
repoConfig: |
 ---
  repos:
  - id: /.*/
    workflow: myworkflow
    apply_requirements: [approved, mergeable]
    allowed_overrides: [apply_requirements, workflow, delete_source_branch_on_merge]
    allowed_workflows: [myworkflow]
    allow_custom_workflows: true
  workflows:
    myworkflow:
      plan:
        steps:
        - run: echo "In Terraform Init and Plan"
        - init
        - plan:
            extra_args: ["-lock=", "false"]
      apply:
        steps:
        - run: echo "In Terraform Apply"
        - apply



# Optionally specify an username and a password for basic authentication
basicAuth:
  username: $$$$$$$$$$$
  password: $$$$$$$$$$



# We only need to check every 60s since Atlantis is not a high-throughput service.
livenessProbe:
  enabled: true
  periodSeconds: 60
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 5
  scheme: HTTP
readinessProbe:
  enabled: true
  periodSeconds: 60
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 5
  scheme: HTTP

service:
  type: NodePort
  annotations: {}
  port: 80
  nodePort: null
  targetPort: 4141
  loadBalancerIP: null
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: []

podTemplate:
  annotations: {}
    # kube2iam example:
    # iam.amazonaws.com/role: role-arn
  labels: {}

# It is not recommended to run atlantis as root
statefulSet:
  annotations: {}
  labels: {}
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1000
    runAsUser: 100
    fsGroupChangePolicy: "OnRootMismatch"
  priorityClassName: ""
  updateStrategy: {}
  # option to share process namespace with atlantis container
  shareProcessNamespace: false

## Optionally customize the terminationGracePeriodSeconds
# terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60

ingress:
  enabled: true
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  apiVersion: ""
  labels: {}
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: >-$$$$$$$$$$$

  path: /  # / for nginx
##  this is in case we want several paths under the same host, with different backend services
#  paths:
#    - path: "/path1"
#      service: test1
#      port:
#    - path: "/path2"
#      service: test2
#      port:
  pathType: ImplementationSpecific

## in case we need several hosts:
  hosts:
    - host: MY_DOMAIN
      paths: ["/"]
  #     service: chart-example1
  #   - host: chart-example.local2
  #     service: chart-example1
  #     paths: ["/lala"]
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local


webhook_ingress:
  enabled: false  # true to create secondary webhook.
  ingressClassName:
  apiVersion: ""
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  path: /*  # / for nginx
## this is in case we want several paths under the same host, with different backend services
#  paths:
#    - path: "/path1"
#      service: test1
#      port:
#    - path: "/path2"
#      service: test2
#      port:
  pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  host:

## in case we need several hosts:
  hosts:
  #   - host: chart-example.local
  #     paths: ["/"]
  #     service: chart-example1
  #   - host: chart-example.local2
  #     service: chart-example1
  #     paths: ["/lala"]
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local
  labels: {}

## Allow to override the /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.cer with your custom one
# You have to create a secret `my-ca-certificates`
# customPem: my-ca-certificates

resources: {}
  # requests:
  #   memory: 1Gi
  #   cpu: 100m
  # limits:
  #   memory: 1Gi
  #   cpu: 100m

## Path to the data directory for the volumeMount
atlantisDataDirectory: /atlantis-data

## Embedded data volume & volumeMount (default working)
volumeClaim:
  enabled: true
  ## Disk space for to check out repositories
  dataStorage: 5Gi
  ## Storage class name (if possible, use a resizable one)
  # storageClassName: value
  accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]

## To keep backwards compatibility
## DEPRECATED - Disk space for Atlantis to check out repositories
# dataStorage: 5Gi
## DEPRECATED - Storage class name for Atlantis disk
# storageClassName: value

replicaCount: 1

## test container details
test:
  enabled: true
  image: bats/bats
  imageTag: 1.9.0
  annotations: {}

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}

# topologySpreadConstraints -- You can use topology spread constraints to control how Pods are spread across your cluster among failure-domains such as regions, zones, nodes, and other user-defined topology domains. (requires Kubernetes >= 1.19).
topologySpreadConstraints: []
#  - labelSelector:
#      matchLabels:
#        app.kubernetes.io/name: aws-example-cluster
#    maxSkew: 1
#    topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
#    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule

serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a ServiceAccount should be created
  create: true
  # Set the `automountServiceAccountToken` field on the pod template spec
  # If false, no kubernetes service account token will be mounted to the pod
  mount: true
  # The name of the ServiceAccount to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name: null
  # Annotations for the Service Account
  # Example:
  #
  # annotations:
  #   annotation1: value
  #   annotation2: value
  annotations: {}
  # IRSA example:
  # eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: role-arn

# Optionally deploy rbac to allow for the serviceAccount to manage terraform state via the kubernetes backend
enableKubernetesBackend: false

# tlsSecretName: tls

environment: {}
# environment:
#   ATLANTIS_DEFAULT_TF_VERSION: v1.2.9

# Optionally specify additional environment variables to be populated from Kubernetes secrets.
# Useful for passing in TF_VAR_foo or other secret environment variables from Kubernetes secrets.
environmentSecrets: []
# environmentSecrets:
#   - name: THE_ENV_VAR
#     secretKeyRef:
#       name: the_k8s_secret_name
#       key: the_key_of_the_value_in_the_secret

# Optionally specify additional environment variables in raw yaml format
# Useful to specify variables refering to k8s objects
# environmentRaw:
#   - name: POD_IP
#     valueFrom:
#       fieldRef:
#         fieldPath: status.podIP
environmentRaw: []

# Optionally specify additional Kubernetes secrets to load environment variables from.
# All key-value pairs within these secrets will be set as environment variables.
# Note that any variables set here will be ignored if also defined in the env block of the atlantis statefulset.
# For example, providing ATLANTIS_GH_USER here and defining a value for github.user will result in the github.user value being used.
loadEnvFromSecrets: []
# loadEnvFromSecrets:
#   - secret_one
#   - secret_two

# Optionally specify additional Kubernetes ConfigMaps to load environment variables from.
# All key-value pairs within these ConfigMaps will be set as environment variables.
# Note that any variables set here will be ignored if also defined in the env block of the atlantis statefulset.
# For example, providing ATLANTIS_ALLOW_FORK_PRS here and defining a value for allowForkPRs will result in the allowForkPRs value being used.
loadEnvFromConfigMaps: []
# loadEnvFromConfigMaps:
#   - config_one
#   - config_two

# Optionally specify google service account credentials as Kubernetes secrets. If you are using the terraform google provider you can specify the credentials as "${file("/var/secrets/some-secret-name/key.json")}".
googleServiceAccountSecrets: []
# googleServiceAccountSecrets:
#   - name: some-secret-name
#     secretName: the_k8s_secret_name

# Optionally specify additional volumes for the pod.
extraVolumes: []
# extraVolumes:
#   - name: some-volume-name
#     emptyDir: {}

# Optionally specify additional volume mounts for the container.
extraVolumeMounts: []
# extraVolumeMounts:
#   - name: some-volume-name
#     mountPath: /path/in/container

extraManifests: []
# extraManifests:
#  - apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
#    kind: BackendConfig
#    metadata:
#      name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-test"
#    spec:
#      securityPolicy:
#        name: "gcp-cloud-armor-policy-test"

initContainers: []
# initContainers:
# - name: example
#   image: alpine:latest
#   command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The init container is running! && sleep 10']

# Install providers/plugins into a path shared with the Atlantis pod
initConfig:
  enabled: false
  image: alpine:latest
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # sharedDir is set as env var INIT_SHARED_DIR
  sharedDir: /plugins
  workDir: /tmp
  sizeLimit: 100Mi
  # example of how the script can be configured to install tools/providers required by the atlantis pod
  script: |
    #!/bin/sh
    set -eoux pipefail

    # example for terragrunt
    TG_VERSION="v0.47.0"
    TG_SHA256_SUM="98d45f6bfbfae84b51364c1ad6920f09ecb4d834908b0535e4e331a9fc6fc75b"
    TG_FILE="${INIT_SHARED_DIR}/terragrunt"
    wget https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/releases/download/${TG_VERSION}/terragrunt_linux_amd64 -O "${TG_FILE}"
    echo "${TG_SHA256_SUM}  ${TG_FILE}" | sha256sum -c
    chmod 755 "${TG_FILE}"
    terragrunt -v

    # example for terragrunt-atlantis-config
    TAC_VERSION="1.16.0" # without v
    TAC_SHA256_SUM="fc3b069cf4ae51e9b7a7d01f09862d1974b260fffb3ec857d661d7b1756fe26f"
    TAC_FILE="${INIT_SHARED_DIR}/terragrunt-atlantis-config"
    wget "https://github.com/transcend-io/terragrunt-atlantis-config/releases/download/v${TAC_VERSION}/terragrunt-atlantis-config_${TAC_VERSION}_linux_amd64.tar.gz"
    echo "${TAC_SHA256_SUM}  terragrunt-atlantis-config_${TAC_VERSION}_linux_amd64.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c
    tar xf "terragrunt-atlantis-config_${TAC_VERSION}_linux_amd64.tar.gz"
    cp -fv "terragrunt-atlantis-config_${TAC_VERSION}_linux_amd64/terragrunt-atlantis-config_${TAC_VERSION}_linux_amd64" "${TAC_FILE}"
    chmod 755 "${TG_FILE}"
    terragrunt-atlantis-config version


# hostAliases:
#   - hostnames:
#     - aaa.com
#     - test.ccc.com
#     ip: 10.0.0.0
#   - hostnames:
#     - bbb.com
#     ip: 10.0.0.2

hostNetwork: false

# these annotations will be added to all the resources
extraAnnotations: {}
# team: example

extraArgs: []
# extraArgs:
# - --disable-autoplan
# - --disable-repo-locking

extraContainers: []
# extraContainers:
#  - name: <container name>
#    args:
#      - ...
#    image: <docker images>
#    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
#    resources:
#      limits:
#        memory: 128Mi
#      requests:
#        cpu: 100m
#        memory: 128Mi
#    volumeMounts:
#      - ...

containerSecurityContext: {}
# containerSecurityContext:
#   allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
#   readOnlyRootFilesystem: true

servicemonitor:
  # to enable a Prometheus servicemonitor, set enabled to true,
  #   and enable the metrics in this file's repoConfig
  #   by setting a value for metrics.prometheus.endpoint
  enabled: false
  interval: "30s"
  path: /metrics
  # Prometheus ServiceMonitor labels
  additionalLabels: {}
  auth:
    # if auth is enabled on Atlantis, use one of the following mechanism
    basicAuth:
      # authentication from the secret generated with the basicAuth values
      #   this will reference the username and password keys
      #   from the atlantis-basic-auth secret
      enabled: false
    externalSecret:
      # authentication based on an external secret
      enabled: false
      # name: atlantis-env
      # keys:
      #   username: USERNAME
      #   password: ATLANTIS_WEB_PASSWORD

# Enable this if you're using Google Managed Prometheus
podMonitor:
  enabled: false
  interval: "30s"

# Set the desired Locking DB type
# lockingDbType: <boltdb|redis>

# Configure Redis Locking DB
# lockingDbType value must be redis for the config to take effect
redis: {}
#  host: redis.host.name
#  password: myRedisPassword
#  port: 6379
#  db: 0
#  tlsEnabled: false
#  insecureSkipVerify: false

# If managing secrets outside the chart for the Redis secret, use this variable to reference the secret name
# redisSecretName: "myRedisSecret"

# Set lifecycle hooks https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/
lifecycle: {}
```

Here is my atlantis.yaml

```
version: 3
automerge: true
delete_source_branch_on_merge: true
parallel_plan: true
parallel_apply: true
projects:
- name: 
  dir: ./ec2
  workspace: default
  terraform_version: v1.6.3
  delete_source_branch_on_merge: true
  autoplan:
    when_modified: ["*.tf", "*.tfvars"]
    enabled: true
  apply_requirements: [mergeable, approved]
  workflow: myworkflow
workflows:
  myworkflow:
    plan:
      steps:
      - run: echo "In Terraform Init and Plan"
      - init
      - plan:
          extra_args: ["-lock=false"]
    apply:
      steps:
      - run: echo "In Terraform Apply"
      - apply
```

I already tried set variable OrgAllowlist: but it still display an error.

Comment: You should immediately revoke your AWS credentials.

Comment: thank you for reminding me to revoke it. I'm facing it the problem but don't have any know how to fix it.